# Reading between <TX> tags in MDF file?

Tags: python-3.7, mdf, asammdf

I'd like to read specific user inputted comments between `<tx>` tags in an MDF/MDF3 file with python. Is this possible using [asammdf](https://pypi.org/project/asammdf/) or [mdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/mdfreader/)?

Parsing through the file the 'pythonic' way is giving gibberish results for some files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the *comment* attributes of the blocks that are interesting to you. See https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#mdf-version-2-3-blocks

Can you give an example of what TXBLOCK needs to be parsed? A MDFValidator screenshot would be nice too.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thank you for the response. The TXBLOCK is one that the user is inputting prior to saving the file. Example of what I would need from the TXBLOCK: user inputted time,  wheel size, velocity, etc.

Comment: looking in it more it seems this data is missing from the .info() command.. .info is creating a dict (properly) which is what i am looking for but the user inputted text are missing... would it be possible to check this on your end if this is user error? i am unable to share the file as it contains confidential information

Comment: most likely the information is stored in the header comment ``print(mdf.header.comment)``